# Is there a way I can filter out all those columns which has dates stored under them - Jupyter(Python)?

Tags: python, date, types, jupyter-notebook, date-format

I need a program that searches for all those columns that have dates stored under them. Since .dtypes would identify dates, strings and many other fields as objects in Python, I need to find a way so that my program only locates such columns that have valid dates. I have looked at other answers but they have mostly shown how to convert a particular data type to a date format, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know which date format you use.
For example you can use time library

```
import time


def is_it_date(date):
    try:
        time.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
        print('yes it is a date')
    except ValueError:
        print('it is doesn`t date')

is_it_date('02/03/2020')
```